# Probability that the Kth drawn ball is the best among N balls

Tags: probability

There are $N$ balls - each having a unique integer value that I do not know beforehand. Integer values are not necessarily from $1, ... ,N$.   I draw $K$ balls without replacement one after the other. I am trying to find the probability that the $K^{th}$ ball has the highest value amongst the chosen ones.

This is the approach I have followed and would like to know if this is correct -

Let each ball be denoted as $R_i$ where $R_1$ is the ball having the least value  and $R_N$ is the ball having the highest value

Let $E_i$ be the event : ball $R_i$ in $K^{th}$ pos AND first K-1 positions are filled with $R_1$ ... $R_{i-1}$

$P(E_i) $= P(ball $R_i$ in $K^{th}$ pos) . P(first K-1 positions are filled with $R_1$ ... $R_{i-1}$)

P(ball $R_i$ in $K^{th}$ pos) = 1 / N because ball $R_i$ could be in any of the N positions

To calculate P(first K-1 positions are filled with $R_1$ ... $R_{i-1}$), I am doing this-

Total number of outcomes = ${N-1 \choose K-1}$

Total number of favorable outcomes = ${i-1 \choose K-1}$

So P(first K-1 positions are filled with $R_1$ ... $R_{i-1}$) = $ \frac{{i-1 \choose K-1}} {{N-1 \choose K-1}}$

So P($E_i$) = $ \frac {1}{N}$ $ \frac{{i-1 \choose K-1}} {{N-1 \choose K-1}}$

We are interested in the event, E =  $E_K$ or $E_{K+1}$ or ... $E_N$ because for i < K, there will always be a higher value ball in the first K positions.

P(E) = P($E_K$) + P($E_{K+1}$) + ... P($E_N$)

So P(E) = $ \frac{1} {N . {{N-1 \choose K-1}}}$ [${K-1 \choose K-1}$ + ${K \choose K-1}$ + ... + ${N-1 \choose K-1}$] = $ \frac{ {N \choose K}} {N . {{N-1 \choose K-1}}}$ = $\frac{1}{K}$

Is the above approach right ?